# como hago esta consulta en Eloquent

Tags: sql, eloquent

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta consulta en Eloquent?

```html
select count(id) as NumeroPreguntas, user_id
from preguntas 
group by user_id 
order by NumeroPreguntas 
DESC Limit 10;
```

He intentado

```html
pregunta::groupBy('categoria_id')->get()
```

pero no funciona, pero si deshabilito el modo Strcit de laravel database, entonces funciona
pero eso no quiero hacer.

si hago esto

```
$res = Pregunta::where('user_id',2)->take(10)->get();

$res = $res->GroupBy('categoria_id')
```

así si funciona, pero el problema es que necesito sacar únicamente los usuarios que más preguntas ha hecho. solo quiero tomar los primeros 10

Y no sé como hacer para que tome 10 con más preguntas. Ya que el codigo sql de arriba si funciona pero en Eloquent no se como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba del siguiente modo a través del `queryBuilder()` y de paso evitas deshabilitar el modo estricto como le mencionas en tu pregunta

```
$data = \DB::table('preguntas')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(id) AS NumeroPreguntas')
        ->select('user_id')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->orderBy('NumeroPreguntas', 'ASC')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Como dentro del método `orderBy()` ya le indique que sea un orden `ASC` para imitar la instrucción `LIMIT` basta usar el método `take()` e indicarle la xcantidad de registros que debe tomar

Comment: Esta genial, ahora funciona. pero ¿Cómo podría cargar la relacion que tiene el user_id  .. en resumen como uso aqui el With('user)

Comment: lo que en este comentario pongo, es una mera opinión; a mi en situaciones similares se me ha complicado muchisimo usar el `eagger loading` entonces lo que yo hago es escribir con Eloquent y sus métodos los joins así cuando en las vistas tenga que recorrer la data lo hago con un solo foreach() y de todos modos obtengo el mismo resultado, por eso te hice una respuesta de este tipo

Comment: @shandow intente usar el Join pero  no me muestra el Nombre :(  en el select me marca error.

Comment: abre una nueva pregunta con tu consulta y la duda que tienes y te ayudo @AlexBurkeCooper