# ¿cómo puedo obtener el nombre de una relacion con QueryBuilder?

Tags: sql, laravel, querybuilder

He  podido  hacer esta consulta :

```html
select count(id) as NumeroPreguntas, user_id
from preguntas 
group by user_id 
order by NumeroPreguntas 
DESC Limit 10;
```

En QueryBuilder  Y quedo de acuerdo a esta respuesta

[Pasar de Sql- Eloquent/QueryBuilder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/210315/como-hago-esta-consulta-en-eloquent/210317?noredirect=1#comment392131_210317)

pero ahora estoy intentando obtener el el nombre del usuario.

--- La tabla con la que quiero hacer Join  Categorias
lo he intentado así.

no muestra error, pero no muestra el nombre de la categoría.

```html
 $data = DB::table('preguntas')
        ->join('categorias','categorias.id','=','preguntas.categoria_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(preguntas.id) as NumeroPreguntas , preguntas.categoria_id','categorias.nombre'))
        ->where('preguntas.user_id','=',2)
        ->groupBy('preguntas.categoria_id')
        ->orderBy('NumeroPreguntas', 'ASC')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Comment: como se llama la tabla con la que quieres hacer join? tambien indicame como se llama la columna donde se almacena el nombre del usuario

Comment: tienes 3 tablas entonces? preguntas, categorias y usuarios?

Comment: añade por favor la estructura de las 3 tablas para comprender mejor

Comment: Bueno en este ejemplo. solo haré una relación de preguntas-categoría, Necesito recuperar el nombre de la categoría.

Comment: entendido deja hago un ejemplo de la consulta, haces la prueba y me dices si te sirvió? sale

Comment: si, Esta bien ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haria los siguientes cambios en tu query

1.- en el método `table()` yo invocaría a la tabla `categorias`

2.-el `join` lo haría con la tabla preguntas, puesto que asumo que la relación es `1:N` donde una categoría tiene muchas preguntas

3.- Donde hago uso del método  `DB::raw()` solo dejo la función de agregación `count()`

4.- En un `select()` por separado pido tanto el `categoria.id` y el nombre de la categoria

5.- Lo demás que tienes de tu código lo dejo igual

```
$data = DB::table('categorias') 
->select('preguntas.categoria_id','categorias.nombre', 
DB::raw('count(preguntas.id) AS NumeroPreguntas'))
->join('preguntas','categorias.id','=','preguntas.categoria_id')
->where('preguntas.user_id','=',2) ->groupBy('categorias.nombre')
->orderBy('NumeroPreguntas', 'ASC') ->take(10) ->get();
```

Y que en la ruta `config/database.php` deshabilites el modo estricto

esta así

```
strict => true
```

debes colocarlo así

```
strict => false
```

Comment: Exactamente algo así igual intente. Y me mostraba esto.

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'NumeroPreguntas' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `preguntas`.`categoria_id`, `categorias`.`nombre` from `categorias` inner join `preguntas` on `categorias`.`id` = `preguntas`.`categoria_id` where `preguntas`.`user_id` = 2 group by `preguntas`.`categoria_id` order by `NumeroPreguntas` asc limit 10)

Comment: si, también lo probé. pero me dice que no encuentra NumeroPreguntas

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper lo anterior y que además en `config/database.php` donde dice `strict => true` lo cambies a `strict => false`

Comment: en mi anterior pregunta igual comente algo de deshabilitar el strict . pero no sé si eso traiga consecuencias.

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper el modo estricto vigila algunos detalles sobre sql por ejemplo puedes checar aqui algunos detalles en mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper cuentame en que termino esto ayudó?

Comment: si ayudó, @shadow. lo  deje así tal y como mencionaste, estaba leyendo igualmente lo de deshabilitar esa parte,  ya que si me dejo la espinita. ahora todo funciona, entonces ahora esa gráfica se ve bien. Si tengo alguna otra duda con otra consulta, espero puedas ayudarme. Es que debo de hacer como 7 gráficas. aprox :S

Comment: claro @AlexBurkeCooper siempre que pueda te apoyo saludos